# asp.net C# SelectedItem.Selected=false Object refrence not set to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selection

```
downlist.SelectedItem.Selected=false;
```

if the downlist's `SelectedItem` is null,after running this code,there will be a error what "Object refrence not set to an object";
how can i modify the code to this

```
downlist.ClearSelection();
```

afert modifying,can i avoid above-mentioned exception

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about the following?

```
if (downlist.SelectedItem != null) 
{
    downlist.SelectedItem.Selected=false;
}
```

Im sure that if I fully understood your problem then there would be a more sophisticated solution, but this should do the trick (unless multiple threads access `downlist.SelectedItem`, which they shouldn't in a typical ASP.Net application).